# angularjs - Grunt serve gives "spawn cmd ENOENT" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, cmd, gruntjs

I'm pretty new to using Grunt and I'm getting this error and I've tried everything anyone has suggested in related posts.

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: 'localhost',
            livereload: 35729
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect().use(
                            '/app/styles',
                            connect.static('./app/styles')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
```

Here is my config

And when I run grunt serve I get the error

```
Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000
Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

I have windows\system32\ in my environmental variables and I've looked over my config files and can't make heads or tails of it. I've additionally run npm cache clean as checking it's installed.

```
C:\Users\Thomas Wollschlager\Documents\webapp>npm -v
3.8.3
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks guys!

`

Answer (score 0):

Run it using command prompt instead of gitBash. Worked for me